# Webview wont work on image click

Tags: facebook, webview, titanium

So the webview should open when i click the "facebook button" which is a image but acts as a button.
Is there a better way to do this, becasue this is not working.
It seemed easy enough with the code though..

```
var fbbutton = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image:"fb.png",
    top:"55%",
    zIndex:"1",
    height:"15%",
    width:"20%",
    left:"2%"   
});

fbbutton.addEventListener("click" , function(e){
         var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({url:'http://www.facebook.com'});
    var window = Titanium.UI.createWindow();
    window.add(webview);
    window.open();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the window an explicit open:

```
fbbutton.addEventListener("click" , function(e){
    var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({url:'http://www.facebook.com'});
    var window = Titanium.UI.createWindow();
    window.add(webview);
    window.open({modal:true}); // Make modal
});
```